# Codeigniter Language, replace with default where not existing

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on a project with Codeigniter, I have multiple language, I load my default language (Italian) in the config file and this works fine.

I noticed if I switch language (let's say from Italian to English) if there is no variable set in the english_lang.php (or whatever file) I just get a blank instead of using the default language.

So, let's say I have this:

***ITALIAN***

```
$lang['main_loading'] = "Caricamento...<br>Attendere.";
$lang['main_titolo'] = "Titolo";
$lang['main_descrizione'] = "Descrizione";
```

***ENGLISH***

```
$lang['main_loading'] = "Loading...<br>Please Wait.";
$lang['main_descrizione'] = "Description";
```

As you can see `main_titolo` is missing in the English file, so when I load the page in english I have an empty title instead of using the Italian (default) string for that specific variable.

Is there a way to use default language for non-exsisting languages lines (variables)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't define "default" as *overridable* language. In fact You define language-files-folder in this var. But You can set default language for example "mydefault", create `mydefault_lang.php`, define there all Your default strings, add this lang-file to `autoload.php` and after that load Your lang files with language-param in app and override it. For example `mydefault`

```
$lang['title'] = "I'm default title";
$lang['header'] = "Hello, world!";
```

...somewhere at, for example, `controllers/user.php`

```
// ....
function login(){
    //                  _desireable lang here_
    $this->load->lang('user','english');
    $this->load->view('user/login');
}
```

Your `language/english/user_lang.php`

```
$lang['title'] = "I'm English title";
```

And in `views/user/login.php`

```
<?php echo $this->lang->line('title'); ?>
```

Comment: @Mr.Web You are welcome. If You get any questions on CI, ask here, I'll try to help